# Spring 3 : Entity Object is getting persisted even after Exception throw

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

transaction has been initiated using following codes in Application Context file:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*InOwnTransaction" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" 
            rollback-for="com.dummy.common.exception.DummyException" />
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"
            rollback-for="com.dummy.common.exception.DummyException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

In Service impl, function for updating entity

```
public Offering selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction(Map<String, String> offeringData) throws DummyException
{
    // search data from DB
    AbstractJpaEntity priceObj = selectEntityByCriteria(Price.class, paramMap);
    // now "priceObj" contain requied data;
    ..
    priceObj.setPublishedStatus(true);
    // some businesslogic which is throwing exception   <-- Point 1 : This is throwing exception
    priceObj.setPrice(23);
    ..
    updateEntity(priceObj);
}
```

Two function calling same above mentioned function "selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction"

```
public boolean updateOffering(Offering offering) // In same Service Impl
public boolean updateOfferingInOwnTransaction(....) throws DummyException // In different Service Impl
```

In Both these function, call to "selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction" is as follow:

```
try
{
    selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction(dataMap);
}
catch (DummyException e)
{
    ....
}
```

**Issue:**
Point 1 is throwing exception and "priceObj" should not be updated in DB, but when "selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction" is called from "updateOffering", it get persisted in DB.

Also only contents that are persisted in DB are contents which are updated in object before exception throw.


Call from "updateOfferingInOwnTransaction" is showing no such error.

I am not able to understand why "updateOffering" is not working as per expectation.

**A workaround**
As quick fix, i did following changes in "selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction", and after that, it worked fine (entity not persisted in DB on exception throw, as expected):

```
Price priceObj1 = new Price();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(priceObj, priceObj1);
updateEntity(priceObj1);
```

But in this also, I do not understand, why this is working ?

**Other configuration details**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation"
            expression="execution(* com.dummy.offering.db.service..*Service.*(..)) || execution(* com.dummy.common.db.service..*Service.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" advice-ref="txAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the transactional configuration? For which classes does that advice apply?

Comment: Hi @AndreiStefan, I added other (may be) relevant configuration in main post. 
context:component-scan has all the pkg which contain above mentioned methods

Comment: One thing: if you rely on `name="*InOwnTransaction" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"` to be working for the method call from `updateOffering` then this won't happen. You make an internal call (self-invocation) for a proxied class: the internal call to `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` from `updateOffering` will be a call to a regular (non-proxied) method. Assuming ServiceImpl is implementing an interface that is maybe called `Service`, is the method `updateOffering` specified in the interface?

Comment: hi @AndreiStefan, updateOffering is written in interface also.
This function is called from controller which autowired that interface (Service)

Comment: I also tried renaming "updateOffering" to "updateOfferingInOwnTransaction", but didn't change anything. What i not tried is adding "throw DummyEcxeption" in "updateOffering" function declaration. (as there is no need to throw one from it )

Comment: What do you do in `catch (DummyException e)
{
    ....
}`?

Comment: So, you are catching that exception and not re-throwing it again? :-) Here's your answer.

Comment: both calling function are doing same work. maintaining a list of failed updates to write in log

Comment: Spring will not know an exception has been thrown, if you are catching it and not re-throwing it. It works in one case and not in other because, as I said above, the call from `updateOffering` to `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` is a call to a non-proxied method.  Spring doesn't treat `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` as a transactional method and, thus, doesn't know how to handle the exception. The only place where the exception would be handled is in  `updateOffering` because, in this case, this is the only transactional method.

Comment: In `catch (DummyException e)
{
    ....
}`, after you do the handling for the failed updates, throw again the `DummyException`.

Comment: Here's [one relevant piece of documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), related to internal calls in proxied instances in Spring.

Comment: I cannot do this. In both the calling function, "selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction" is running in loop (for 100s of offering). I just have to make log for failed updates. If i throw exception, remaining update will not happen.

Comment: Can you move `updateOffering(Offering offering)` to another Service Impl?

Comment: I copied same function in other service and serviceimpl, and it is working thr perfectly. I don't understand why it is not working in original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rely on `name="*InOwnTransaction" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"` to be working for the method call from `updateOffering` then this won't happen. You make an internal call (self-invocation) for a proxied class: the internal call to `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` from `updateOffering` will be a call to a regular (non-proxied) method.

I **strongly** suggest to read carefully [this section of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).
To directly apply what you have in your code with the sample in the documentation: `SimplePojo` is your `ServiceImpl`, `foo()` is your `updateOffering` and `bar()` is your `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction`. Think about a proxy as an entirely new class that intercepts calls to your own methods and classes.

- So, basically, when you call `updateOffering` from your controller you are calling `updateOffering` on a different class (which is not `ServiceImpl`) instance.
- This new class applies the *transactional behavior* (starting a new transaction, associating transactional resources with the current thread etc) and then calls the **real** `updateOffering` from your own `ServiceImpl`.
- `updateOffering` then calls `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction`, but since this call is like `this.selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` then the call would be on your `ServiceImpl`, not the newly created class that acts as a proxy. Because of this, Spring treats your `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` as a regular, nothing special method.

On the other hand, if `selectiveUpdateInOwnTransaction` is called from anther class, that another class will call that method on the proxy, and this is why it works if you call it from a different `ServiceImpl`.

In that section of the documentation, there is an *ugly* solution to this restriction

```
public class SimplePojo implements Pojo {

    public void foo() {
        // this works, but... gah!
        ((Pojo) AopContext.currentProxy()).bar();
    }

    public void bar() {
        // some logic...
    }
}
```

but the real acceptable approach would be to redesign your classes a bit: move `updateOffering` to another class.

Comment: thanks @Andrei. Though i am not using "AopContext". I got the idea.
I have retaken bean from application context and called function selectiveUpdate using that bean Object. It is working.

Comment: i good link for proxy expose is http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/28036-exposing-the-current-proxy-exposeproxy. Just for info for new comers like me